# SQL - count each distincted row

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I would like to analyze content of the table by monitor distincted values by specific field and how many occurrences there are of each distincted value.

Let' say we have this table ...

```
Field
000
000
000
111
111
222
333
```

So result would be:

```
Field Count
000    3
111    2
222    1
333    1
```

What would the query to achieve this result?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. And use COUNT(*).

Comment: You want to aggregate your table rows so as to get one result row per field. Whenever you say "I want to aggregate the rows to get one result row per *xyz*", group by *xyz*. Then apply the appropriate aggregation functions (SUM, COUNT, …) for whatever aggregate you want to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply:

```
SELECT field, count(*) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY field
```

there isn't much else to say on this, being perhaps the simplest of all aggregate queries.

if you're monitoring, however, you might need to keep track of how many things were before and how many there are now. i'm using SQL SERVER syntax for this but the technique would be fairly universally applicable:

if you make a history table with a date, field and count column set, then run this every minute (say):

```
  INSERT INTO history

  SELECT iter.iteration, t.field, t.count(*) as count
  FROM table t
  CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT GetUtcDate() as iteration) iter 
  GROUP BY field
```

Then you'll get a bunch of rows inserted every minute with the changing counts and an incrementing date of when that data was saved. all you need to do to compare how things changed is then:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  history o 
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  history n
  ON 
    o.field = n.field AND 
    o.count <> n.count AND
    o.iteration = '2001-01-01 00:00:00' AND
    n.iteration = '2001-01-01 00:01:00'
```

we use full outer join so that fields may come and go completely (all of a kind deleted, new ones added etc) between iterations. we filter to show only counts than have changed. this query also demonstrates how a table can be joined to itself which is a handy trick

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Field, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM table
GROUP BY Field
ORDER BY Count
```